# When using Visual Studio console to wait for a file to be created, it never gets to the code when the file created - why?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static long oldFileSize;
        static bool firstTimeSaveGame = false;
        static string rootSaveGameDirectory;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\saves");

            // Enable events
            fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            rootSaveGameDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\saves";
            if (!Directory.Exists(rootSaveGameDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(rootSaveGameDirectory);
            }

            string fileToWatch = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySave";

            while (!File.Exists(fileToWatch))
            {
                if (File.Exists(fileToWatch))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileToWatch);
                    oldFileSize = fi.Length;
                    firstTimeSaveGame = true;
                    CopyFileOnChanged(fileToWatch, fileToWatch);
                    Console.WriteLine("File copied first time...");

                    break;
                }
            }

            fileWatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileToWatch);
            fileWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(fileToWatch);

            // Add event watcher
            fileWatcher.Changed += FileWatcher_Changed;
            fileWatcher.Created += FileWatcher_Changed;
            fileWatcher.Deleted += FileWatcher_Changed;
            fileWatcher.Renamed += FileWatcher_Changed;

            var maxThreads = 4;

            // Times to as most machines have double the logic processers as cores
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(maxThreads, maxThreads * 2);

            Console.WriteLine("Listening");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I used a breakpoint and it's getting into the while loop to the inner if line :

```
if (File.Exists(fileToWatch))
```

Then I'm running the application and creating the file, but it never gets inside the while loop to the lines after the second if.

But it does get to the line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Listening");
```

Why when I create the file it never gets inside the while loop and never reaches the lines :

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileToWatch);
oldFileSize = fi.Length;
firstTimeSaveGame = true;
CopyFileOnChanged(fileToWatch, fileToWatch);
Console.WriteLine("File copied first time...");
    
break;
```

Comment: The condition inside the loop is the opposite of the loop condition, unless the file gets created in the precise moment you are inside the loop, but before the condition, it will never hit the if branch.

Comment: Why would you do this? Get rid of that loop; the FSW will tell you when a file is created; you don't need to batter your IO system senseless with a tight infinite loop waiting for a file to appear

Comment: @CaiusJard the problem is that the file not exist yet so how the created event will know if the specific file created ? the created event watch for the path directory not specific file. in my project when i put in the textBox a path it will automatic watch for a path but if i put in the textBox a path with file name it will watch for the file name.  the problem is that the file name is not exist yet so i can't put it to be watched in the textBox.

Comment: @CaiusJard what i can do is in the created event to use e.FullPath to get the created file but then what should i put in the textBox to watch for ? i can't put the re the path of where the file will be created because i want to watch for the file created and changes.

Comment: @CaiusJard this is a link to my MainWindow.xaml.cs maybe you can watch it and see how to do it ? https://pastebin.com/RbW0w8y7 if needed i will make a new thread about it. my project in wpf csharp. it's not the same project in my question but i'm using the same concept from the console project in the wpf project. i can also uplaod the whole wpf project to github if needed.

Comment: Watch the parent, and have IncludeSubdirectories set to true?